# Connection error with mule salesforce connector

Tags: salesforce, mule

trying to connect to salesforce sandbox with salesforce connector is resulting in following error,

Test connection failed: Check authEndpoint. It must contain '/services/Soap/u/'. authEndpoint specified

the url for connect is https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/29.0/.

the default connect url that appears on adaptor config is https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0.

has anyone faced a similar error. if yes is there a workaround.

thanks 
Santosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0

the /u/ means partner API

the /c/ means enterprise API

Comment: would this means mule salesforce connector does not support Enterprise Web Services WSDL. [link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_partner.htm)

Comment: it means they're using the partner API for login, anything more than that you'd have to ask Mule.

Answer (score -1):

https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/32.0 
https://your sfdc instance /services/Soap/u/32.0 
will work

Comment: Adding some details about the solution would make it a complete answer!